# Write to particular part of text file NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a text file like this:

```
lorem ipsum

some text

even more lorem ipsum
```

How do I select that "**some text**" bit of the file and and write to it eg. "more lorem ipsum". 
**Note: The "some text" section will not have a constant value.** 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using line-replace npm module:**

```
const lineReplace = require('line-replace')
lineReplace({
  file: 'yourtextfilename.txt',
  line: 3, // line number starts from 1 
  text: 'more lorem ipsum',
  addNewLine: true,
  callback: ({ file, line, text, replacedText, error }) => {}
})
```

PS: This question has been already answered multiple times before, please do your own research before posting a question.

Comment: “*This question has been already answered multiple times before*” If so, flag as a duplicate and don’t answer it.

Comment: But he looks like a beginner so I just gave an even simpler answer that probably isn't in the other answers. Also, I can't flag for duplicates yet.